# Sorting contents of attachments in numerical form in arraylist

Tags: java

I am trying to get all non-transformed files in the /attachments folder and put in array and sort non-transformed attachment array alphanumerically using java.
Here is my code for

```
// get all non-transformed files in the /attachments folder and put in array 
File f = new File("D:\\template_export\\template\\attachments");
ArrayList<String> attachmentFiles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));
System.out.println("attachmentFiles :" + attachmentFiles);
```

And I need to sort the following output:

```
attachmentFiles :[0.gif, 1.gif, 10.gif, 11.gif, 12.gif, 13.gif, 14.gif,
15.gif, 16.gif, 17.gif, 18.gif, 19.gif, 2.gif, 20.gif, 21.gif, 22.gif, 
23.gif, 24.gif, 25.gif, 26.gif, 27.gif, 28.gif, 29.gif, 3.gif, 30.html, 
31.messages, 32.messages, 4.gif, 5.gif, 6.gif, 7.gif, 8.gif, 9.gif]
```

I tried with below code:

```
Collections.sort(attachmentFiles);
for(String counter: attachmentFiles){
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

But it's not getting sorted.

Comment: What's the output it's giving? It should ideally get sorted the way you want.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort it according to the numeric filenames (e.g., 4.gif before 11.gif)?

Comment: Yes,I need the output to be sorted by numberbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two strings of digits of a different length as if they are numbers it is necessary to left fill the shortest string with 0 chars.

So first it is necessary to search the first point in both strings. Compare their positions and fill with 0 the "shortest" number with zeros as in the following code.

```
Collections.sort(attachmentFiles,new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
         int point1 = o1.indexOf('.');
         // If no point is present we assume it is present as last position
         if (point1 == -1) {
             point1 = o1.length();
         }
         int point2 = o2.indexOf('.');
         // If no point is present we assume it is present as last position
         if (point2 == -1) {
             point2 = o2.length();
         }
         if (point1 > point2) {
             char[] chars = new char[point1-point2];
             Arrays.fill(chars, '0');
             o2 = new String(chars) + o2;
         } else if (point1 < point2) {
             char[] chars = new char[point2-point1];
             Arrays.fill(chars, '0');
             o1 = new String(chars) + o1;
         }
         return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is required, custom logic to sort list of data. May be below explanation would help you write the same.

```
Collections#sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the
>   specified comparator. All elements in the list must be mutually
>   comparable using the specified comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2)
>   must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the
>   list).

it is how you can pass custom logic. And now how to create `Comparator` logic.
Example -

```
List<String> attachmentFiles = ...;
Collections.sort(attachmentFiles,new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // logic - 
        //a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second
    }
    });
```